# RealmSwift - How to override hash function when migrating pre-existing Class to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, hash, realm

I have an existing `Movie` class that I now wish to store using the `RealmSwift` Framework. Previously I had conformed `Movie` to the `Hashable` protocol (for performing `Set()` operations on arrays of Movies), but this is made redundant by `Realm`'s requirement to conform to its `Object` protocol.

However, now I get an error with my (re)declaration of the `hash(into hasher: _)` function (as needed by `Hashable`):

```
Overriding declarations in extensions is not supported
Overriding non-open instance method outside of its defining module
1. Overridden declaration is here (ObjectiveC.NSObject)
```

[image: Screenshot of the error messages from declaring func hash(...), as previously required to conform to Hashable]

---

I've checked many issue reports on the `Realm` git repo to no success (and some have been incorrectly marked as closed, I believe):

- [Conformance to Hashable is broken for objects without primary key](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4705)
- [Error when implementing Hashable in Xcode 10](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5927)
- [Support adding own methods to objects](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/909)

I've tried with and without a declared `primaryKey`, as well as putting a dummy initial (guaranteed unique) id via `dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString` - although it should be noted that `Movie()` is ***NEVER*** called - I always use the (now convenience, with this Realm refactor) `convenience init(title: String, id: String, cast: String )` initialiser.

Some suggestions include overriding a `hash` or `hashValue` variable, but the latter has been made redundant by the former (and the former still doesn't work for me - in this example case, I am just using the `id` parameter for the `Movie`'s `hash/hashValue`:

```
override var hash: Int {
  return id.hashValue
}

override var hashValue: Int {
  return id.hashValue
}
```

---

My `Movie` code is as follows (with the fatal error on `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {` as shown in the above screenshot):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import EventKit
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class Movie: Object {
 dynamic var title: String = ""
 dynamic var id: String = ""
 dynamic var cast: String  = ""

 convenience init(title: String, id: String, cast: String ) {
    self.init()
    self.title = title
    self.id = id
    self.cast = cast
 }

 override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
 }

 func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(title)
    hasher.combine(id)
    hasher.combine(cast)
 }
}
```

---

An example of the `Set()` arithmetic that I wish to perform on arrays of Movies, `[Movie]`. In this example I am checking if `subSetOfMovies` is a sub-set of `allMovies`, *if-not* then add it to the list of `allMovies`:

```
 if !Set<Movie>(subSetOfMovies).isSubset(of: Set(allMovies)) {
   allMovies.append(contentsOf: subSetOfMovies)
 } else {
   print("subSetOfMovies is a subset of allMovies, thus it is not added.")
 }
```

Note: I wish to use Set arithmetic because it is very fast. For long lists of movies I do not wish to check that each movie, individually (say with a for-loop), is *not* included in the `allMovies` array.

---

Basically, I want to be able to manually reconform my `Movie` class to `Hashable` so that I can perform set arithmetic on it (as I did before I started to implement `RealmSwift` to my `Movie` Model). However, as things currently stand, it seems that I can't with `Realm` - unless I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I realised that it wasn't really necessary to do set arithmetic for "efficiency" on such small array lengths (if there were ~100,000,000 elements then using set arithmetic would make for worthwhile gains). My solution used the id (UUID) to find and replace movies using the standard array methods